# What's the difference between Gold Edition and Deluxe Edition of Resident Evil 7?

Tags: version-differences, resident-evil-7

Gold Edition of RE7 was announced recently. Looks like it will include all existing DLCs and two newly introduced.

Existing Deluxe edition includes base game and season pass, which unlocks all DLCs as well.

For me these two editions look very similar.

What's actual difference between them if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [description on CapCom's blog](http://www.capcom-unity.com/capkel/blog/2017/09/05/return-to-the-mansion-with-resident-evil-7-gold-edition-and-dlc-on-december-12th), this is basically the same as the Deluxe edition, but with all the DLC on disc rather than as downloads.

In other words, it's a [Game Of The Year edition](https://www.giantbomb.com/game-of-the-year-edition/3015-3825/) without actually being *called* Game of the Year.

Comment: On a side note, I think Unreal was the first game to use the term Gold edition back in 1999 which bundled Unreal with its expansion Return to Na Pali.

Answer (score 2):

*Resident Evil 7: Biohazard Gold Edition* comes with the full game of Resident Evil 7: Biohazard and includes the Season Pass and *Not a hero* DLC.

*Resident Evil 7: Biohazard Deluxe Edition* comes with the full game of Resident Evil 7: Biohazard and includes the Season Pass.

Comment: The Not a Hero DLC will be free to all owners of Resident Evil 7 regardless of which edition it is (Standard, Deluxe, or Gold) when it comes out in December.

Comment: Not a hero not on the disk (gold edition), it's free for download.

Answer (score -1):

To me it looks to me like both versions would have the same content, since the Season Pass includes all DLCs that are listed in the Gold Edition as well. 
However since the Deluxe Editon comes with a Season Pass, Capcom could add more DLCs to the Season Pass later that the Gold Edition wouln't include then. But that's probably not gonna happen after all the time, I guess. So, get the cheaper version or simply the Deluxe Edition with the Season Pass if they got the same price anyway.

Answer (score -2):

there are some changes in the story mode environment, furnitures rearranged, and coins for different purposes in the safe box, i found these in the Gold edition

Comment: I believe coin changes are between normal and madhouse difficulties and not related to game version at all. As for environment changes, can you add few examples?